# Does $\gamma(t)=e^{it^2} , t \in [0,\sqrt{2\pi}]$ represent the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, plane-curves

$$
\begin{align}
\gamma(t)=e^{it^2} , t \in [0,\sqrt{2\pi}]
\end{align}
$$

Is my thinking correct that $\gamma$ represents the unit circle correct?

Comment: Yes. We have just a "non-constant speed", but $\gamma$ is supported on $S^1$.

Comment: [WolframAlpha agrees](http://po.st/90zxtl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenters said, you are right: this is a circle

More generally, if $\Gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb C$ is a curve, and $f:[c,d]\to [a,b]$ is a strictly increasing continuous function such that $f(x)=a$ and $f(d)=b$, then the composition $\Gamma\circ f$ is a different *parametrization* of the same geometric object.

In your case, $f(t)=t^2$ and $[c,d] =[0,\sqrt{2\pi}]$; also, $\Gamma(t)=e^{it}$ and $[a,b]=[0,2\pi]$.